# How do I make my AUX cable register as an input device instead of an output device?

Tags: audio, windows-11, realtek-hd-audio

My computer is an Acer Nitro 5 laptop. I read about a method to send PS5 audio from monitor to computer using an AUX cable, so I tried it out. However, I use Windows 11, and when connecting the AUX cable to the audio jack, Realtek tries to mark it as headphones, speaker out, or headset. I need the line in to be an input device, but I have no idea how to make it register as one instead of the output device Realtek wants it to be.

Comment: Change the settings in the Realtek Control panel. Make sure the other end is connected to line-out. If you do line-in on both sides, it will not work.

Comment: @LPChip Both laptop and monitor only have one audio jack. Realtek audio console will only change the analog connection to headphone, speaker out, or headset.

Comment: Then you need a cable that will fool it into thinking you have a headset plugged in, then it will use the mic input. That's not going to be the best audio quality & will also be mono.

Comment: Connect a normal microphone to ensure that the laptop at all can be switched to mic or line in. I have a feeling it can't. Its possible you need a mic/headphone splitter cable for this to work.

Comment: So i'd need to get a splitter cable, connect that to the laptop audio jack, and connect the aux cable to the mic side of the splitter?

Comment: Yes, that should work.